# Can your toothbrush reinfect you if you have a cold?

Tags: common-cold, infection

I was in a supermarket yesterday and saw the following on a toothbrush:

[image: "Got a cold? Change your toothbrush." sticker on toothbrush package]

I found the advice repeated on the [Colgate website](http://www.colgate.co.uk/app/Colgate/UK/OralCare/OralHealthCenter/OralHygieneBasics/HowtoBrush.cvsp?Article=HowToBrush#anchor4):

> It is also very important to change toothbrushes after you've had a cold, since the bristles can collect germs that can lead to reinfection.

**Can you be reinfected by your own toothbrush if you've had a cold?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This depends on what you were sick with, and how long the toothbrush was not used since you last had the sickness.

- You CAN get reinfected with a bacterial infection (e.g. strep throat) from a toothbrush

  http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/article/000639.htm

  > Most people with strep are contagious until they have been on antibiotics 24 - 48 hours. They should stay home from school, daycare, or work until they have been on antibiotics for at least a day.
  >
  > **Get a new toothbrush after you are no longer contagious, but before finishing the antibiotics.** Otherwise the bacteria can live in the toothbrush and re-infect you when the antibiotics are done. Also, keep your family's toothbrushes and utensils separate, unless they have been washed.
- Viruses can also be retained on toothbrushes, with research showing minutes to 24 hours to 48 hours depending on the virus. Example:

  http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7931767

  > *"The effectiveness of a u-v toothbrush sanitizing device in reducing the number of bacteria, yeasts and viruses on toothbrushes."* Glass RT, Jensen HG.- Department of Oral Pathology, University of Oklahoma College of Dentistry
  >
  > Seventy-two sterile toothbrushes were exposed to Herpes Simplex Virus, Type I and seventy-two sterile toothbrushes were exposed to Parainfluenza Virus, Type III. The Pollenex DS60 Daily Dental Sanitizer consistently killed both viruses on all of the toothbrushes treated. **Both viruses were consistently retained on non-treated toothbrushes for at least 24 hours.**

  However, in case of common cold virus, the reinfection risk is presumably reduced by the fact that you have already developed immunity to the strain you had.

Comment: Good answer, but could you give some more details on your last point about cold virus immunity?

Comment: @Tom77 - the fact that you have recovered from cold means that your immune system developed enough antibodies that you now have resistance to that particular strain. And the virus on a toothbrush won't be replicating and mutating.

Comment: Other question: *does it hurt* to get reinfected? Your specific immune system is up and running, and butchers anything that comes in via the toothbrush. This is even more true if you haven’t taken antibiotics.

Comment: Could it help to put the toothbrush in boiling water? Do the viruses survive, even if the toothbrush dries completely?